# IE changes the mode to Quirks when site loads first

Tags: html, joomla2.5, doctype

I am working on joomla 2.5 and when I load my site in Internet Explorer the document mode for IE changes to Quirks. The sites first load changes to Quirks mode and when I change the mode again it works fine.

I checked my document type in `template.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

This is the document type in `xml` file and this type is said to fix the issue [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_10019982_turn-off-quirks-mode-disable-internet-explorer-html.html)

Comment: do you have any character before <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W...?

Comment: No I didn't have anything before that line

Comment: Its working fine only in IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Myself fixed the issue.

Just checked the script tags added elsewhere. I found it is inside system plugin and I just removed it and now it is working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Comment: have only the php script before that

Comment: Is there anything you have echo... from the script?

Comment: sorry, not getting you, but as per the code you have pasted, there are an xml tag, try to set the xml tag throught php header not print or display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space at prior to the  tag is a Byte Order Mark (BOM). This was throwing all pages into "Quirks" mode in IE.
Try using another editor like notepad++ and Convert to UTF-8 without BOM.